# looking for 3-SAT special cases

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for 3-SAT special cases which are solved in Polynomial time and their algorithms.
any links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the excellent (but a bit hard to read) paper by Thomas J Schaeffer: [The Complexity of Satisfiable Problems](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/lieber/courses/csg260/f06/materials/papers/max-sat/p216-schaefer.pdf) which generalizes satisfiability problems to an infinite class of problems like 3SAT, Not all Equal 3Sat etc, and shows that each problem is either in P or NP-Complete.

The paper also determines necessary and sufficient conditions to determine if a particular problem is in P or NP-Complete (called the [Dichotomy Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem)).

I suppose you will also find an P time algorithm in there (not very sure) for the problems which are in P.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

2-SAT is in P (but MAX-2-SAT isn't, funnily enough), I'm not sure about monotone 3-SAT. Almost all occurence restrictions are still NPC.

As always in these matters, Garey/Johnson's Computers and Intractability is your friend.